# Testing jQuery Hover with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, bdd, jasmine

How should I go about testing a jQuery Hover action with Jasmine?
My jQuery looks like

```
$('.class').hover(
  function() { $('#someid').hide(); },
  function() { $('#someid').show(); }
);
```

How could I simulate moving the hover action with jasmine and expect that 'someid' element is hidden and shown as it should?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to directly trigger a mouseover event and then test for the appropriate behavior:

```
it("should do something on hover", function() {
  $('.class').trigger('mouseover');
  expect($('#someid')).toBeHidden();
  $('.class').trigger('mouseout');
  expect($('#someid')).toBeShown();
});
```

`$('#someid')` must be in the DOM.  The best way to do that is through a fixture.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Figured it out sometime after I posted the question. However, forgot about updating my question!

Comment: can you explain what you mean by using a fixture?

Comment: I believe he means Jasmine Fixtures. Basically fixtures are HTML templates of your app where you want to test your DOM specific JS. http://rubygems.org/gems/jasmine-fixtures